# ¿Cómo crear usuarios estando registrado?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Estoy diseñando una aplicación en *Ror* y tengo un administrador que necesita crear usuarios, pero hasta ahora no me lo permite, por consola me sale este mensaje:

> Filter chain halted as: require_no_authentication rendered or redirected

No sé qué más hacer, estoy ocupando la *Gema devise*.

Comment: Para poder ayudarte necesitamos muchos más datos sobre el problema. Dónde salta el error exactamente? Podrías mostrar el controlador? Cómo identificas a los administradores dentro de tu aplicación?

Answer (score 0):

la idea es tener un usuario administrador que genere otros usuarios pero que estos a la vez no tengan privilegios de usuarios no?
Si es así podrías utilizar [CanCanCan Gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/cancancan/versions/1.13.1) con esto podes dar un privilegio a un usuario y otros no, creo que es lo que necesitas básicamente, y con respecto a tu problema seria bueno que nos proporciones código o algo para poder saber de donde surge el error, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Si no requieres que los usuarios se puedan registrar a si mismos solo quita la opción `:registerable` del modelo.